# Perl -- replacing metacharcters with regular expressions

Tags: regex, perl, file, metacharacters

I'm having problems while replacing metacharacters using regular expressions. 
The phrase I want the regular expressions replace the metacharacter is:

```
ley+sobre+propiedad+literaria+1847
```

And the code I use is that below:

`$file =~ s/\+/\s/; # --> Replace the +`

But it seems to only replace the first metacharacter and the result is:

```
leysobre+propiedad+literaria+1847
```

What shoud I use?

Comment: You might make it more readable by using a character class `[+]` instead of `\+`. But that's just a preference :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The `\s` is a character class and not a valid escape for strings. The second part of a substitution is taken as a string.
2. To replace all occurrences (“globally”), use the `/g` switch on the replacement.
3. Single-character transliterations can also use the `tr///` operator.

Assuming you want to replace `+` by a space:

```
tr/+/ /;
```

or

```
s/\+/ /g;
```

If you want to decode URLs:

```
use URL::Encode 'url_decode';
my $real_filename = url_decode $file;
```

See the [documentation for URL::Encode](https://metacpan.org/module/URL::Encode) for further information.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is not connected to metacharacters. The substitution `s///` replaces only the first occurrence of the pattern unless told to replace all of them by the `/g` option.

BTW, `\s` is interpreted as plain `s` in the replacement part. If you want `\s`, you have to specify `\\s` to backslash the backslash (as in double quotes). Thus the output is in fact

```
leyssobre+propiedad+literaria+1847
```

Note the double `s`.

Answer (score 1):

use the `s/\+/ /g` to replace globally.